# error while adding custom source to SSIS using Data Tool 2015

Tags: ssis

each time i try to add ssis custom component,  this error pops up

note:- this component works fine on data tool 2010 and 2013 , this problem happens only on Data Tool 2015

is there any thing missing and how to fix it

my .net framework 4.0

the error as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xFm3.png)

```
TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio
```

---

```
The component could not be added to the Data Flow task.
Could not initialize the component. There is a potential problem in the ProvideComponentProperties method.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Error at Data Flow Task [DTS [7]]: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.IDTSComponentMetaData100 Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.PipelineComponent.get_ComponentMetaData()'.
   at CustomProparties.Class1.ProvideComponentProperties()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostProvideComponentProperties(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper)


------------------------------

Method not found: 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.IDTSComponentMetaData100 Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.PipelineComponent.get_ComponentMetaData()'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this worked for me:

"Please open your csproj file, and remove `<EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>` element or set the value to False in the reference to Microsoft.SQLServer.DTSPipelineWrap.dll , then rebuild your project."

Although this is a solution for the component being targeted for SSIS 2012 instead of SSIS 2015 and this is not my situation, it worked.

Source:
[Social MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0e93028b-8d71-4a3c-84aa-3e6799ba75e0/systemmissingmethodexception-getcomponentmetadata?forum=ssdt)